# Minimum Distance required to add PolyLine between two points

Tags: android, google-maps

```
Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(myPos, itemPos).color(Color.BLUE));
```

For the PolyLine I created above, my app crashes. The distance between myPos and itemPos is 0.019 miles. Is there a minimum distance required to draw a line between two points using PolyLine?

Comment: There shouldn't be. As far as I'm aware Google's navigation uses a poly line as the route.

Comment: Please give crash logs from Logcat

Answer (score 0):

@jb15613 I believe you are correct with that.

You can however use an API v3 to draw a line between two points:

```
var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), new google.maps.LatLng(37.4519, -122.1519)],
    strokeColor: "#000000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 10,
    geodesic: true,
    map: map });
```

The ‘geodesic’ /geometric library is if you wish to have the shortest path. You need to account the facet that the earth is curved. Please add the libraries parameter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
```